# how to convert a result of a method to String in Java?

Tags: java

Here is the code, that works:

```
public class WorkshopApplicationMyCollection {
static void listOfPeople(List<String> someList) {
    for (int i = 0; i<someList.size(); i++){
        if (i == someList.size()-1) {
            System.out.print(someList.get(i) + ". \n");
        } else {
            System.out.print(someList.get(i) + ", ");
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> listOfPeople = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfAuthorities.add("Musk");
    listOfAuthorities.add("Davinchie");
    listOfAuthorities.add("Gates");



    System.out.print("Number of people " + listOfPeople.size() + ". Those people are ");

    listOfPeople(listOfAuthorities);

    
}
```

}

What I'm trying to do is to make a result of a method listOfPeople() to be a string by itself so that I could put it into the sentence. when I'm doing like this:

```
System.out.print("Number of people " + listOfPeople.size() + ". Those people are " + listOfPeople(listOfAuthorities));
```

the IDE says that the method has to not be void. How to make the method return string on it's own?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the method in `System.out.println` it should return `String` instead of `void`. Think of `void` as a procedure that doesn't return anything. You want a method that returns `String` which can be used as a subject of printing out to a console.

(I prefer [`String.join(CharSequence delimiter, Iterable elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) to chain String elements:

```
static String listOfPeople(List<String> someList) {
    return String.join(", ", someList) + ". \n";
}
```

Then it shall be used as:

```
System.out.print("Number of people " + listOfPeople.size() + ". Those people are " + listOfPeople(listOfPeople));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should return a `String`, not call `System.out.println` directly. A common way of doing this is streaming the list and then joining it:

```java
static String listOfPeople(List<String> someList) {
    return someList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "", ". \n"));
}
```

Comment: Wow! awsome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, a `void` function obviously returns nothing.

Here is a simple generic approach without using a `Stream`:

```
public static String flattenList(List<?> list)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            sb.append(list.get(i));
            if(i < list.size()-1) sb.append(",");
            else sb.append("\n");
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

If you just want to output the individual values, you can use something like that:

```
people.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.join("delimiter", list).

You coded wrong some name of variables, so I've corrected to you. Summarizing:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WorkshopApplicationMyCollection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> listOfAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfAuthorities.add("Musk");
        listOfAuthorities.add("Davinchie");
        listOfAuthorities.add("Gates");

        System.out.print("Number of people " + listOfAuthorities.size() + ". Those people are " + String.join(" and ", listOfAuthorities));

    }
}
```